# $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\varphi''\geq 0$???

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find a function $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. a  $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ function with compact support) such that 
$$\varphi''(x)\geq 0\qquad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
I don't know if there exist such function.

Comment: What about $\varphi\equiv0$?

Comment: No it is so elementary

Comment: You should specify that you're looking for non-zero functions if you find such a solution unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, is there a (nonconstant) convex function with compact support?  In fact, you cannot have (from left to right) values $0,$ nonzero, $0,0$ in a convex function.

*Proof*
In a convex function: If you have (from left to right) values $0,a,0$ then $a \le 0$.  If you have (from left to right) $a,0,0$ then $a \ge 0$.